# Can't use lineHeight in checkbox in react-native elements

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I'm using the checkbox from React Native Elements.
I need to create a space between each checkbox, but I can't.

Bellow the code from the first CHECKBOX: "APRENDER SOBRE O BENEFICIO"

```
 <View style={ styles.checkboxContainer }>
          <CheckBox   
            title='Aprender sobre o benefício'       
            checked={ benefits }
            component={ TouchableWithoutFeedback }
            textStyle={ benefitsTextStyle }
            iconType={"material"}
            checkedIcon={"check"}
            checkedColor={"#00BAEC"}
            uncheckedIcon={"lens"}
            uncheckedColor={"#E3E4E4"}
            size={10}
            containerStyle={{lineHeight: 40, backgroundColor:'red'}}
          />
.
.
.
.
</View>
```

I've also tried to use this PROPS `style={ styles.checkboxItem }`  with those proprietors:

```
  checkboxItem: {
    margin: 5,
    padding: 5,
    backgroundColor: 'red', // debug
  },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your container has fixed height try to use flex properties like justifyContent and alginItems, for example:

```
.checkboxContainer: {
  flexDirection: 'column',
  justifyContent: 'space-between', //You can also try 'space-around'
}
```

Also you can just wrap up each checkbox into a View to set stict size for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution worked for me.
I imported the **checkbox** from **"React-Native-Element"**.
You can add space between Icon and title.
Refer below Code..

```
<CheckBox
      center
      title="you are doing here"
      checkedColor="white"
      checked={check1}
      onPress={() => setCheck1(!check1)}
      iconRight
      containerStyle={{
        backgroundColor:'red',
        flexDirection:'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
      }}
      textStyle={{fontWeight: '900',marginEnd:100,color:'white',width:200}}
    />
```

I just added textStyle Property **textStyle={{marginEnd:100}}**
You check [Snack Here](https://snack.expo.dev/@saurabh_chavan/react-native-element-checkbox).
if you have multiple item then depend on textlength icon will display you want to display all item in line same size from text then add **textStyle={{marginEnd:100,width:200}}** in textStyle property.